# What happens to your controlled undead when you no longer hold a rod of undead mastery?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

The rod of undead master states

> While holding a rod of undead
>   mastery, you can control twice as
>   many Hit Dice of undead as you
>   normally could. For instance,
>   if you can normally control 12
>   HD of undead, you can control
>   24 HD of undead while holding
>   the rod.

What happens when you are no longer holding the rod? Do all undead above the number you can normally control become released? If so can you just hold the rod again to regain control over them?

Or is the word "hold" in this instance simply meant to mean in your inventory and not actually "held" (I can't imagine many spellcasters sleeping with this thing held in their hand)

Comment: RE: "I can't imagine many spellcasters sleeping with this thing held in their hand." Why not? I mean, it's kind of important, after all! `;-)` (Besides, it's what *sovereign glue* is for!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan  Haha good point! I guess with all the times it would be super difficult to hold onto (climbing, sleeping, entering most places that don't like creepy skull rods in your hand) I was thinking to myself... can it really mean that? That would cause quite an uproar when you fall asleep and half your undead start murderizing the party!

Comment: That's why Pale Masters graft a skeletal undead hand onto themselves - so they can always hold on to their Rod!

Comment: Oof. I just realized I might be approaching this question wrong, having been distracted by the *rod of undead mastery.* You might want to pose another question like *Do previously-controlled undead seek revenge on their former controllers?* or *Can evil mindless undead be manipulated without being controlled?* or something.

Comment: @HeyICanChan That was actually what I thought the question was asking the *first* time, and I concluded it was actually the question you answered only upon rereading.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing happens when you let go of the rod, unless you're controling them via [Rebuke Undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#turnOrRebukeUndead).

[Animate Dead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/animateDead.htm) says (in part):

> No matter how many times you use this spell, however, you can control only 4 HD worth of undead creatures per caster level. If you exceed this number, all the newly created creatures fall under your control, and any excess undead **from previous castings** become uncontrolled. (You choose which creatures are released.)

(emphasis mine)

Animate Dead only checks the HD of undead you can control when being cast; if your effective caster level or you set down the rod, your currently-controlled undead creatures are still controlled until such time as you cast Animate Dead again (thus triggering a HD check).

Note that [Control Undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/controlUndead.htm) explicitly only checks HD on casting (the only mention is in the "target" section, and [Command Undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/commandUndead.htm) has no HD level (the target is a single undead creature).

[Turn/Rebuke Undead](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#turnOrRebukeUndead) is different: turning, destroying, and rebuking undead would only check the undeads' HD at the time of channeling, but commanding undead via Rebuke states:

> At any one time, the cleric may command any number of undead whose total Hit Dice do not exceed his level.

I don't have Libris Mortis in front of me, so I'm not 100% sure that the rod's power would affect the HD one can command; if it does, and the bearer drops the rod, the "extra" undead would stop being controlled.

Comment: That line in *animate dead* is specifically adjudicating solely the situation where you exceed your controlled undead via casting the spell again. It does not comment one way or the other on what happens if you exceed your limits by lowering those limits. Your conclusion does not follow from the evidence you have presented.

Comment: There are any number of spells whose effects are semi-permanent and caster-level-dependent, without question as to when the CL is checked (ie., when the spell is cast). There's no reason to think that a Permanent Image would get smaller (or fizzle) if the caster lost a few levels (or a CL-boosting item); why think that Animate Dead works any differently?

Comment: *Animate dead* is an instantaneous spell that establishes a relationship between you and the newly-undead creature that is independent of the spell itself. By contrast, *permanent image* is permanent, and so its effect is a part of the spell effect. That difference is massive, and is more than enough reason to see the two as reacting differently to otherwise-similar stimuli. Since the *rod of undead mastery* affects the relationship between the wielder and some undead creatures, rather than any particular casting of any particular spells, it is a different situation from a caster level bonus.

Answer (score 3):

## Several methods exist to control undead

Just to be clear, a creature that holds the *rod of undead mastery* (*Magic Item Compendium* 175–6) (10,000 gp; 3 lbs.) doubles its available Hit Dice for *all* methods it uses to control undead. For example…

- The 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*command undead*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#command-undead) [necro] (*PH* 211) doesn't measure the number of undead that can be controlled by the undeads' Hit Dice. The spell is unaffected by the *rod*.
- The 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*animate dead*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#animate-dead) [necro] (*PH* 198–9) allows controlling up to 4 HD of undead per caster level that the caster animates with the spell. The *rod* increases this to 8 HD.
- The 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*control undead*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#control-undead) [necro] (*PH* 214) allows the caster to control up to 2 HD of undead per caster level. The *rod* increases this to 4 HD.
- A neutral or evil cleric (and some other creatures) may [rebuke undead](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#turn-or-rebuke-undead) (*PH* 159–60) to such a degree that he commands them. Normally, a creature can control up to HD of undead equal to its level in the class that grants the supernatural ability rebuke undead. The *rod* doubles this HD.

In addition to these, magic items, other spells, other class features, and even some monster special abilities control undead and measure that control in HD. The *rod* doubles the HD that can be controlled using all these methods… while the *rod*'s held.

### This DM would rule that letting go of the *rod* leaves some undead uncontrolled

The number of Hit Dice of undead a creature can control doubles *only* when the creature holds the *rod of undead mastery*. The *rod*'s description says this *twice*.

However, as [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/115567/8610) implies, this could mean literally nothing: if the *rod* increases the number of HD of undead a creature can control using an effect while the *rod*'s held, *dropping* the *rod* shouldn't change how those effects were *already* used! This reading, though, leads to the possibility of handing around the party's one lone *rod of undead mastery* to each party member individually who can—through whatever means—control HD of undead… essentially *doubling* the entire party's HD of controlled undead yet *dividing* the price for being able to do so by the number of party members! ("*You* get a *scroll of animate dead*! And *you* get a *scroll of animate dead*! And *you*…!")

Minionmancy is already one of the game's most time-consuming strategies, and this DM would be *extremely* hesitant to run the *rod*'s effect that way, even if it *is* technically accurate.

Instead, this DM would have a creature's number of HD of controlled undead return to normal when the creatures abandons the *rod*… *and* have *that* mean that the creature's control over some its HD of undead just *ends*. This reader imagines three ways a DM can adjudicate this:

- The creature picks which undead remain under its control.
- The undead that have been controlled the longest are freed.
- The undead that were controlled most recently are freed.

(Other options may certainly exist!) Were a player in this DM's campaign considering for his necromancer PC a *rod of undead mastery* I might poll the table. (My players are a magnanimous, thoughtful bunch.) Were this DM considering for an NPC necromancer antagonist a *rod of undead mastery*, he'd go with the third option. (That is, this DM tries to make things easy on himself, so he'd *want* to go with the first option, but the second option is *sort of* like what happens when the caster of an *animate dead* spell animates *too many* dead, and the third option actually makes to this DM the most sense and makes for better plots: the *last* undead is usually the skeleton army or the unholy colossus or whatever, so breaking the *rod* frees it from the antagonist's control. Yay, Team Protagonist. Maybe.)